# De-duplicating record in SQL but keeping ID

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a table which contains the following fields

- `id`
- `entCode`
- `postCode`
- `addressLine1`
- `addressLine2`
- `addressLine3`
- `addressLine4`
- `addressLine5`

Both `id` and `entCode` are unique integers

What I want to do is de-dup and for this of course I can do

```
select postCode, addressLine1, addressLine2, addressLine3, addressLine4, addressLine5
from addresses
group by postCode, addressLine1, addressLine2, addressLine3, addressLine4
```

However what I also want to do is to return the first ID and `entCode` of that address but I can't quite get my head around it - it would be `select top 1 id, entcode` but to match `postCode` + all 5 address fields I am not sure if I need to be doing a join or something else.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a database tag would really help.

Comment: Hi Gordon - thanks for the tip.  I think row_number could be handy in same cases but this time round I will use the min() function.  Also next time I will include sample + desired to make it easier for all.  Thanks agian!

Comment: . . `min()` is actually not the correct answer to the question, because you are specifically asking for the *first id and entcode*, not the smallest values of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I get this right, but maybe you're just looking for `min()`?

```
select min(id), min(entCode), postCode, addressLine1, addressLine2, addressLine3, addressLine4, addressLine5
from addresses
group by postCode, addressLine1, addressLine2, addressLine3, addressLine4
```

Comment: brilliant of course!  thank you.  Simplicity is the key to longevity :)

Answer (score 0):

In almost any database you can use `row_number()`:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by postCode, addressLine1, addressLine2, addressLine3, addressLine4, addressLine5 order by id) as seqnum
      from addresses a
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```